# Change visibility button from titlebar programmatically?

Tags: android, visibility, titlebar

I have a problem button visibility. I have 2 button from titlebar.One of them edit, one of them done. First I want to see just edit button and when i clicked edit button, edit button visibility will be false and done button visibility true.

I get their id from xml and when i click one of them i want to change visibility but edit.setVisibility(); it doesnt work.What is wrong?I can see edit button.I want to change buton visibility programmatically.

Can anybody have any idea?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final boolean customTitle = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    edit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    done=(Button)findViewById(R.id.done);

    edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.main);

    if ( customTitle ) {
       getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.main);
    }
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <Button android:id="@+id/edit"
          android:layout_width="57px"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="edit"/>

   <Button android:id="@+id/done"
          android:layout_width="57px"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="done"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please use the action bar for this sort of behavior. The action bar is native on Android 3.0+ and there are various libraries for providing an action bar on earlier versions of Android (e.g., ActionBarSherlock).

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing the android:orientation parameter in your LinearLayout.

Second, if you want to change between edit and done you can do this:

```
edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
done.setVisibiluty(View.VISIBLE);
```

and the opposite to change to edit button again.. With View.INVISIBLE the button will not show but still use the space where it was.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setFeatureInt` just sets the resource ID for the title, which will cause a new inflation of the layout resource, which will be placed in a system `FrameLayout` called `id/title_container`. This can be inspected using the Hierarchy Viewer in eclipse.

Essentially, you end up with two instances of the main layout. One set as the content view (below the title) and the other set as the title. When you call `findViewById`, it will only look in the content view for any views matching the ID. This means that the `edit` and `done` buttons you retrieve are the ones in the content view.

If you want to access the buttons in the title area, you can use

```
    View v = getWindow().getDecorView();
    edit=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    done=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.done);
    edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

This will search through the whole view structure of the window, not just the content view, thus solving your problem.